# Facebook like and Fancybox2 not displaying or protocol mismatch

Tags: https, facebook-like, fancybox-2

I'm having an odd issue with Fancybox2 and Facebook's like button code. I've tried various ways to integrate the like button using facebook's generated code, yet it just doesn't work. Here's what I've done and the errors I'm getting (the question will come up at the end)

**a.** I attempted to use the iframe code, as seen in the tips and tricks section of Fancybox's page. The button shows up, I can click it but I get the following errors:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://jsfiddle.net/TheEternalAbyss/67Fxp/ from frame with URL
>   https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=21#channel=…l.net&channel_path=%2F_display%2F%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df2ddbc4ff%26.
>   The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.

So if the like button is clicked, it just doesn't send anything to facebook and is functionally dead.

**b.** I decided to try the HTML5 method from Facebook's like code generator and everything seems ok, but I get no button to show up within the clicked image. When I inspect the element I see the div and all the html in there, just I see nothing on the rendered page.

This can be seen specifically here...
http://jsfiddle.net/TheEternalAbyss/67Fxp/

three things to note: 1) I have the ifram code in there, so if you click on an image you will see the button, but you get the protocol mismatch errors as well. 2) the grey bordered areas (in the page and when you click an image is the HTML5 method, but it works only if I have the html code of

`<div class="fb-like" data-href='' data-send="false" data-width="400" data-height="25" data-show-faces="true" data-font="lucida grande"></div>`

in the html area of jsfiddle. 3) As you if you click on an image, what should be appearing in that grey box is the like button but I get a big fat nothing.

So finally my question:

**How can I get either method to work.. either resolving the protocol mismatch issue, or making the html5 method work?**

Thank you in advance for your assistance. I really need to figure this out thanks!

**EDIT**
THe parse function does help getting the facebook like to show up, however I'm still having protocol mismatch problems. I'll play with it some more, any more asistance in welcome, thank you!

Comment: Have you ever found the workaround? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Not particularly. The like counts, but it only appears to count on the page where the like button appears. I don't see any activity on facebook newsfeed or to the wall of the user who clicked the like to begin with. I read up on facebook developer network about this too and it seems it's a recorded issue that facebook is trying to resolve, but I have no idea if it truly is a bug or is facebook has any immediate plans on fixing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the HTML5 version, you will need to trigger a JavaScript call to render the button (if it's not rendered on Page Load). Since you need to show the Like button on page load, call the `FB.XFBML.parse()` function and you'll see that the button will appear.

What you need to do is edit the onclick event for fancybox so that the `FB.XFBML.parse()` is called when the user clicks the image.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely give that a try and update the status of this issue

Comment: The parse function does help getting the facebook like to show up, however I'm still having protocol mismatch problems. I'll play with it some more, any more asistance in welcome, thank you!